# Java : Crash when put decimal number [RESOLVE]

Tags: java, android, crash

Ok, my problem is : I've created an application to calculate my IMC (French Word). But when i try to enter my height or my weight in decimal in the EditText, it return me this error :

```
03-27 18:52:25.459 31274-31274/fr.imc.oxyz0n359.imc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: fr.imc.oxyz0n359.imc, PID: 31274
                                                                  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.5"
                                                                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:521)
                                                                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
                                                                      at fr.imc.oxyz0n359.imc.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:27)
                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5675)
                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22641)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

And here is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView Resultat;
private Button Calcul;
private EditText Poids, Taille;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Resultat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Resultat);
    Calcul = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Calcul);
    Poids = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Poids);
    Taille = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Taille);
    Calcul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int Etape = Integer.parseInt(Taille.getText().toString())*Integer.parseInt(Taille.getText().toString());
            int Result = Integer.parseInt(Poids.getText().toString())/Etape;
            Resultat.setText("IMC : " + Result);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Thanks for your answers, OxYz0n359.

Edit : I resolve the problem, thanks for your answer i change the code to :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView Resultat;
private Button Calcul;
private EditText Poids, Taille;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Resultat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Resultat);
    Calcul = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Calcul);
    Poids = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Poids);
    Taille = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Taille);
    Calcul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            double etape = Double.parseDouble(Taille.getText().toString())*Double.parseDouble(Taille.getText().toString());
            double result = Double.parseDouble(Poids.getText().toString())/etape;
            Resultat.setText("IMC : " + result);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"1.5" is not an integer, you need to parse it as Double and only after that convert to integer in way most suitable for you. Also, in java variable names start from lowercase, I will suggest you to keep up with this custom.

Comment: Worth noting that unless you need the performance of a floating point type and you are VERY aware of the problems it comes with, it’s almost always better to use a true decimal type when doing calculations. In Java this would be BigDecimal.

Answer (score 0):

You're not parsing an integer. When calling parseInt('code') it does not understand what the decimal is. Try using parseDouble('code') or its equivalent. You will also produce a wrong answer since you're trying to store a double inside of an int data type.

Answer (score 0):

`"1.5"` cannot be parsed as an `integer`.  It is a floating representation of a number.
 Whereas the exception :

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.5"

What you need is `Double.parseDouble()` or `Float.parseFloat()`.
If you don't care of the round part in the result, you can still round it :

```
double taille = Double.parseDouble(Taille.getText().toString());
int Etape = (int) (taille * taille);
```

If you care of the round part, you should replace your `int` vars by floating numeric types such as `double` (or float) and probably use `BigDecimal` to perform computations and get more precise results.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) the NumberFormatException is triggered because you parse a string that does not represent an integer. Indeed, "1.5" is a double and not an integer.

You should consider using [Double#parseDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-) as in your usecase the height is a double